# Password protecting the copying, retrieving, and downloading of images

Tags: image, passwords, password-protection

There is a website that I use that has a lot of images. Whenever I try and copy the images (for example, to copy into MS Word), Word request a username and password. If I don't give the right password, then it just gives a blank box the size of the image. I haven't seen this behavior on any other sites before, but it seems like a nice technique. Can I copy this effect on my website?

I would link to the site, but it requires an account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

via ctrl+c, ctrl+v, or click with the right button of the mouse ? I think it is made in javascript, who listen some keyboards events. It is not secure, it is easy do disable it in fact.

for example, to ctrl+c/v

function verify(){
var ctrl=window.event.ctrlKey;
var key=window.event.keyCode;
if (ctrl && key==67) {alert("CTRL+C"); event.keyCode=0; event.returnValue=false;}
if (ctrl && key==86) {alert("CTRL+V"); event.keyCode=0; event.returnValue=false;}
}

function click() { 
if (event.button==2) { alert('dont do this'); }
}

Comment: It's not like that; it's much less intrusive. When I copy the image, it works fine, but then when I **paste** the image into word, a dialog box (in word) shows up, asking for a username and password.

Comment: It's Florida Virtual School (FLVS.net)